# Fix race condition when doing http get request angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below function, which checks if the user has entered the right password and username. This functions correctly however the function returns before the success/error functions are fired.

Therefore the function always returns true, what would be the best method to have the function return the right value.

```
angular.module('services.security', [])
    .provider('securityService', function() {



        this.$get = function ($q, $location, $rootScope, $window, $injector) {
             ...
             loginCheck: function(username, password) {
                    var failed = true;                      

                    $injector.get('$http').post(AUTH_URL,
                        {username: username, password: password}, {loginType: "cancel"}
                    ).success(function loginSuccess(data) {

                        failed = false;

                    }).error(function loginFailure(data, status) {

                        failed = true;

                    });

                    return failed;
                },
```

Comment: What is `$injector`? Is that an async post?

Comment: `$injector` is Angular's dependency injection service, but I don't know why @OP is injecting the injector rather than just injecting `$http` directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some research into JavaScript Promises. That's what you're working with here. The problem is that HTTP calls are (generally) asynchronous, meaning that the code doesn't wait for them to finish before continuing. This is where promises come in.

Instead of returning the true/false value directly, your function should instead return a promise representing the true/false value. You can then attach handler functions to it that essentially say "whenever the HTTP call finishes, pass the result into these functions. If you're using a more recent version of Angular, e.g. 1.4.4+ or 1.5.x (not sure about Angular 2, but probably this will still apply), the `$http.post()` method returns a promise anyway, so you can return that directly.

The key thing is the `.then()` method of promises. This takes 2 arguments: the first argument is a success function, the second is a failure function. So you should just rewrite your code like this:

```
loginCheck: function(username, password) {
  var failed = true;                      

  return $injector.get('$http').post(AUTH_URL,
    {username: username, password: password}, {loginType: "cancel"}
  );
}

// ...

// somwhere else where securityService.loginCheck() is used
securityService.loginCheck(username, password).then(
  // success
  function(data) {
    // handle successful login
  },
  // failure
  function(data, status) {
    // handle failed login
  }
);
```

This is how asynchronous code is written these days. Definitely read up on Promises and asynchronous concepts i general, it's super important in modern web development.

- [An introduction to promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)
- [Promises A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com/)
- [MDN's documentation on the recent built-in Promise type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [`$q`, Angular's promise service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 4):

You would want to return the promise.
So you can just return your http-call:

`return $http("...");`

In your code you can then just use this returned promise to check if it was succssful:

```
loginCheck(u, p).then(function() {
    //success
}, function() {
    // error
});
```